# Problema al descargar un excel desde la web con Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, oracle, excel

Intento descargar el siguiente archivo excel desde un enlace del banco de la república de Colombia mediante Python 3:

[Promedio movil TRM ultimos 20 dias](https://totoro.banrep.gov.co/analytics/saw.dll?Download&Format=excel2007&Extension=.xlsx&BypassCache=true&path=%2Fshared%2FSeries%20Estad%C3%ADsticas_T%2F1.%20Promedio%20m%C3%B3vil%2020%20d%C3%ADas%2F1.1.TCM_%C3%9Altimos%20dos%20meses%20cargados%20al%20sistema%20IQY&lang=es&NQUser=publico&NQPassword=publico123&SyncOperation=1)

El excel contiene información relativa al tipo de cambio entre COP y USD.

Al intentar descargarlo como se haría desde cualquier otro link, me descarga un excel informando el siguiente erra:

[image: Mensaje de error]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import urllib.request
outfilename = "test.xls"
dls = "https://nam10.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftotoro.banrep.gov.co%2Fanalytics%2Fsaw.dll%3FDownload%26Format%3Dexcel2007%26Extension%3D.xlsx%26BypassCache%3Dtrue%26path%3D%252Fshared%252fSeries%2520Estad%25C3%25ADsticas_T%252F1.%2520Promedio%2520m%25C3%25B3vil%252020%2520d%25C3%25ADas%252F1.1.TCM_%25C3%259Altimos%2520dos%2520meses%2520cargados%2520al%2520sistema%2520IQY%26lang%3Des%26NQUser%3Dpublico%26NQPassword%3Dpublico123%26SyncOperation%3D1&data=02%7C01%7Crwelte%40anasac.cl%7C2d9c65b2a2b24c0d245108d7d802cca6%7C487ca045f86943a183d6ab515aa60499%7C0%7C0%7C637215378862951003&sdata=v8IAgBC%2FB6jynXF9udrMNzznv7nDl13BmIRkxbFFgwo%3D&reserved=0"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(dls, outfilename)
```

Entiendo que el problema es que Oracle BIEE esta en JS y que por ello no puedo descargar mediante mi código sencillo.

¿Cómo podría descargar el archivo correctamente con python?
Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que suplantar un [agente de usuario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agente_de_usuario) que el servidor acepte simplemente:

```
import urllib.request


dls = "https://nam10.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftotoro.banrep.gov.co%2Fanalytics%2Fsaw.dll%3FDownload%26Format%3Dexcel2007%26Extension%3D.xlsx%26BypassCache%3Dtrue%26path%3D%252Fshared%252fSeries%2520Estad%25C3%25ADsticas_T%252F1.%2520Promedio%2520m%25C3%25B3vil%252020%2520d%25C3%25ADas%252F1.1.TCM_%25C3%259Altimos%2520dos%2520meses%2520cargados%2520al%2520sistema%2520IQY%26lang%3Des%26NQUser%3Dpublico%26NQPassword%3Dpublico123%26SyncOperation%3D1&data=02%7C01%7Crwelte%40anasac.cl%7C2d9c65b2a2b24c0d245108d7d802cca6%7C487ca045f86943a183d6ab515aa60499%7C0%7C0%7C637215378862951003&sdata=v8IAgBC%2FB6jynXF9udrMNzznv7nDl13BmIRkxbFFgwo%3D&reserved=0"
outfilename = "test.xls"

proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
opener.addheaders = [
    ('User-Agent', ("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) "
                    "AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                    "Version/10.1 Safari/603.1.30"
                    ))]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url=dls, filename=outfilename)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! funciono a la primera